# pass parameters in url via php

Tags: javascript, php, html

i am tying to pass some parameters in my URL via php. Below is my code i have tried.

```html
<button  onclick="window.location.href='process2.php?name=' .$fname. '&Usrname=' .$name "  style="border-radius:5px;margin-right:10%;font-size:20px;box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);background-color:#d29dfa">
```

i guess there is some errors with the qoutes. how to solve it?

Comment: You need to close your concatenation after `$name` so that it reads `' . $name . '`.

Comment: … and escape your single quotes. Make sure you post the context next time so silly people like me don't miss that, too. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `window.location.href` which will return the current URL from the address bar, you can use `window.location.assign()` which will open a new document for a given address.

Check below:

```html
<?php
  echo '<button onclick="window.location.assign(\"process2.php?name='.$fname.'&Usrname='.$name.'\");" style="border-radius:5px;margin-right:10%;font-size:20px;box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);background-color:#d29dfa">';
?>
```